# Error when Querying Parse with PHP

Tags: php, html, parse-platform

I am trying to use the Parse.com SDK with PHP. I have downloaded and installed the SDK and I have successfully created a test object.

However, when trying to retrieve an object with a basic query using the sample code provided in the Parse docs and when I try to run it I get:

**Fatal Error:** Class 'ParseQuery' not found in **/home/jameshilton/public_html/index.php** on line **109**

I would have guessed that it is not linking to the SDK properly but everything else is working fine.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the code of the class `ParseClient` in on [GitHub](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk/blob/master/src/Parse/ParseClient.php) I can see that the classes are declared in the namespace `parse`. So when you need an object from the Parse library you need to select the namespace. This can be done in two ways.

At the top of your file write:

```
use \parse;
```

or when instantiating the class:

```
$query = new \parse\ParseQuery
```

And remember to make sure the files are included either through an autoloader (composer?) or manually using `include` or `require`.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I had forgotten to declare the ParseQuery class.